# In Ruby what does the line "class ClassName < Base" mean in this context

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, module, radix

Given the code

```
require 'gdata'

class Contacts
  class Gmail < Base
```

What does it mean when we say "< Base", does it mean inheriting from the Base class defined in the module gdata, in that case wouldn't there be a conflict with some other module that may be required too.

Or does it mean something else?

Comment: Is there a specific conflict that you're wondering about?

Comment: No I was not not worried about a specific conflict, I was wondering whether the Base meant something special or if it was expected to come from "gdata". I also came across one other snippet where there were a number required statements. Since I did not see it namespaced as it is normally done ( like in Activerecord::Base)  I was wondering if it had a special meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base has no special meaning.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > Base.inspect
NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Base
```

Unless a class called Base or Contacts::Base is defined in gdata, that example should generate an error.

```
class Base
  def self.hello
    "oh hi!"
  end
end

class Base2
  def self.hello
    "ahoy!"
  end
end

class Contacts
  class Base
    def self.hello
      "hi 2 u"
    end
  end
  class Gmail < Base
  end
  class Gmail2 < Base2
  end
end

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :024 > Base.hello
 => "oh hi!" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :025 > Contacts::Gmail.hello
 => "hi 2 u" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :026 > Contacts::Gmail2.hello
 => "ahoy!"
```

Comment: Thank you Kimmmo, so "< Base" doesn't stand for anything special.

Answer (score 0):

The class `Gmail` is just a normal nested class definition, that happens to be a subclass of `Base`.  Apparently `Base` is defined somewhere in the file `gdata` but nowhere does it say that `gdata` is a Ruby *module* and, if it were a module, you did not show it being mixed into (with `include`) `Contacts` so I'm not sure there are any *conflicts* to worry about.

Comment: Thank you Ray "Apparently Base is defined somewhere in the file gdata" - this answers my question. Since I have come across "Base" as in ActiveRecord::Base I was wondering if it was a generic name to expose certain functionality. And since in this example it isn't namespaced I was wondering if it came from "gdata" or if it came from somewhere higher up the hierarchy.